# Subdivision of a small category

Tags: ct.category-theory, simplicial-stuff

I am reading about subdivision of a category from this paper:

http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2010/REUPapers/Delgado.pdf

At the page 4, the author of this paper gives the first example of a subdivision of a categrory with one object and one nonidentity morphism.

He claims that there are only two nondegenarate simplices in $\Delta/ \mathcal C$. While in my opinion there infinitiley many of them since there is exactly one nondegenerate simplex in each dimension. Am I right?

Another thing is that it looks that I do not understand this construction yet because I have such a problem.

If we have two nondegenerate simplices $([q],\mu), ([q+1],\mu^{'})\in [\Delta/ \mathcal C]$ then the only possible maps between them are those induced by injections $d_i: [q]\to [q+1]$. But for a surjection $s_i:[q+1]\to [q]$ which repeats $i$, the maps $d_i, d_{i+1}$ are right inversions of $s_i$, so $d_i$ and $d_{i+1}$ are elementary equivalent and it means that in $Sd\mathcal C$ there is exactly one morphism between an object to another object which has greater dimension. So $Sd\mathcal C$ is a poset and its reealization is homemorphic to $[0,1)$.

But $\mathcal C$ is a category that is $\mathbb Z_2$ (considered as category with one object) so realization of $Sd\mathcal C$ cannot be contractible. Where do I make a misteake?

Comment: You are correct: the nerve of the category in question has infinitely many non-degenerate simplices.

Comment: Thanks. But I still can't figure out why I get contractible subdivision od this category.